# Failed to get the contents of a pointer in C

Tags: c

I have the following statements in a program in C and they cannot be changed:

```
struct struct_handle;
struct struct_handle *com_Connect(const char *val1, void *priv, int timeout_msec, enum com_ErrorCodes *com_errno);
```

I create this function:

```
void foo(struct_handle *handle)
{
    enum com_ErrorCodes com_errno;

    do
    {
        handle = com_Connect("val1", NULL, 10000, &com_errno);

        if(handle == NULL) 
        {
            //ERROR handle is NULL
        }
    }
    while(handle == NULL);

    //HERE handle is not NULL
}
```

This is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct struct_handle *handle;

    foo(handle);

    if(handle == NULL)
    {
        //ALWAYS handle IS NULL
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function that i create foo() is to send a "handle" and receive it once it is different from NULL, I know it is different from NULL because the function returns and I have validated the content inside the function. The problem is that when I want to occupy that "handle" outside the function it always tells me that it is NULL, that makes me think that the problem is when I return from the function I am not correctly obtaining the content of the pointer. What would be the correct way to obtain it?

Comment: `handle = com_Connect("val1", NULL, 10000, &com_errno);` you need a pointer to a  pointer for this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, all function parameters are pass by value.  That means any changes to the parameter `handle` in `foo` are not reflected in the calling function.

You should change `foo` to return a `struct_handle *` and assign that to `handle` in `main`.

Change the function to:

```
struct_handle *foo()
{
    enum com_ErrorCodes com_errno;
    struct_handle *handle;

    do
    {
        handle = com_Connect("val1", NULL, 10000, &com_errno);

        if(handle == NULL) 
        {
            //ERROR handle is NULL
        }
    }
    while(handle == NULL);

    return handle;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
handle = foo();
```

Comment: Or pass the pointer by reference, and allow the function to return an error code